# Why does Jay steal the pennies of Gloria and Manny?

Tags: plot-explanation, modern-family

In *Modern Family*, Season three episode *Aunt Mommy*, we got to know Gloria and Manny were trying to collect hundred pennies to buy a lottery for a long time. But when Manny was done collecting it Jay stole some of the pennies which it seems Gloria realized but let slide.

What was the reason for Jay's such action?

Answer (score 4):

This is because he saw that Gloria and Manny were bonding over the collecting of the pennies. It was more fun for them to find the pennies together then actually reach their goal.

That's why Jay stole a few so that the penny hunt will bring them joy longer.

Additionally Manny is very naïve, he believed 100 lucky pennies would buy them a inning lottery ticket... the chances of that are close to zero so when that happened he would be heart broken.

So the second reason is to spare him some heartbreak over a crushed dream.

Answer (score 4):

Because collecting the coins was something he Manny liked to do with his mom. It represented hopes and dreams they had for the future. Finding all the coins meant the end to that special time he used to share with his mom and Jay thought it would be nice if they could have that special time just a little longer.